# Measurability of inferior limit and limit of a Lévy Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I'm reading about Lévy Processes.

As a definition of a recurrence and transient Lévy process we have:

Def. For a Lévy process $\{X_{t}\}_{t\geq 0}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is called recurrent if $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}|X_{t}|=0\space a.s.$

It is called transient if $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}|X_{t}|=\infty\space a.s.$

Then the book says that events are measurables because 
$$\{\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}|X_{t}|=0\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(n,\infty)}\{|X_{t}|<1/k\}$$
and
$$\{\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}|X_{t}|=\infty\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{t\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(n,\infty)}\{|X_{t}|>k\}.$$

I'm trying to prove these equalities but I don't get the compatibility between the definition of limit and infierior limit with these expressions.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us prove the first equality under the assumption that the process
is right-continuous. The other properties about Levy process (e.g.,
independent increment) are irrelevant. To facilitate typing, we consider
the case $d=1$ only (the general case is the same).

Let $X:[0,\infty)\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a map such
that for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $X(\cdot,\omega)$ is a right-continuous
function. We assert that 
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\lim\inf_{t\rightarrow\infty}|X(t,\omega)|=0\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(n,\infty)}\{\omega\in\Omega\mid|X(t,\omega)|<\frac{1}{k}\}.
$$
Proof: Let $\omega\in LHS$. Let $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary.
Since $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{t\geq s}|X(t,\omega)|=0$, there
exists $s_{0}$ such that $\inf_{t\geq s}|X(t,\omega)|<\frac{1}{k}$
whenever $s>s_{0}$. Choose $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_{0}>\max(n,s_{0})$.
Then $\inf_{t\geq n_{0}}|X(t,\omega)|<\frac{1}{k}$. Now $\frac{1}{k}$
is not a lower bound of the set $\{|X(t,\omega)|\mid t\geq n_{0}\}$,
so there exists $t_{0}\geq n_{0}$ such that $|X(t_{0},\omega)|<\frac{1}{k}$.
By right-continuity of the function $X(\cdot,\omega)$ and density
of $\mathbb{Q}$, we can choose $t_{1}\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(t_{0},\infty)$
such that $|X(t_{1},\omega)|<\frac{1}{k}$. Clearly $t_{1}\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(n,\infty)$,
so $\omega\in RHS$.

Conversely, let $\omega\in RHS$. We construct a strictly increasing
sequence $(t_{l})$ such that $t_{l}\rightarrow\infty$ and $|X(t_{l},\omega)|\rightarrow0$.
It will follow that $\omega\in LHS$. Put $k=n=1$, choose $t_{1}\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(1,\infty)$
such that $|X(t_{1},\omega)|<1$. Suppose that $t_{1},t_{2},\ldots,t_{l}$
have been chosen. Choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>t_{l}+1$.
Now $\omega\in\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(n,\infty)}\{\omega\mid|X(t,\omega)|<\frac{1}{l+1}\}$,
so there exists $t_{l+1}\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(n,\infty)$ such that $|X(t_{l+1},\omega)|<\frac{1}{l+1}$.
By recursion theorem, we obtain a sequence $(t_{l})$ which has property:
$t_{l+1}>t_{l}+1$ and $|X(t_{l+1},\omega)|<\frac{1}{l+1}$, for all
$l\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $t_{l}\rightarrow\infty$ and $|X(t_{l},\omega)|\rightarrow0$.

Comment: So clear! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need other properties about Levy process. Otherwise, these two identities does not hold. For example, if $X:[0,\infty)\times\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is just a map, the first equality fails to hold. For, we may define $X(t,\omega)= 0$ if $t$ is irrational and $X(t,\omega)= 1$ if $t$ is rational. Then $\{\omega\mid \liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} |X(t,\omega)|=0\}$ is $\Omega$ but RHS is empty.

Comment: Will be enough if each set has intersection with the set that gives right-continuity to the process?

Comment: Yes, if the process is right-continuous, then the two equalities hold. Some textbooks assume that all Levy processes are cadlag but some do not. You need to specify all the premises at the beginning.